# List of lists: how to delete all lists that contain certain values?

Tags: python, list

There's a list of lists (or it could be tuple of tuples). For example:

```py
my_list = [
  ['A', 7462],
  ['B', 8361],
  ['C', 3713],
]
```

What would be the most efficient way to filter out all lists that have a value `'B'` in them, considering that the number (or other values) might change?

The only way I came up with so far is using a for/in cycle (or rather a list comprehension) but it's very inefficient in this case, so I'd like to know if it's possible to avoid using a loop.

Comment: Your code example is a tuple of tuples, the title is list of lists, and you mention dicts in the question. The answer is different depending on what structure you are actually working with: please be specific

Comment: Regardless the DS, you still have to use some forms of loop

Comment: Have fixed the issues with my question. Doesn't really matter if it's lists or tuples since they are easily convertable, in this particular case.

Comment: As @DanielHao said you cannot avoid for loops

Comment: It would help to have your inefficient code example to see if we can do better. You need a loop in some form and that's not bad - they are not inherently inefficient.

Comment: Is the 'B' (or whatever) always the first value in the list? Or can it be anywhere in the list?

Comment: @tdelaney My inefficient code is how choices for Django models are stored. -_-

Comment: @tdelaney Always the first in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new list, filtering out the stuff you don't want. In python this is usually done with a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [sublist for sublist in my_list if sublist[0] != 'B']
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind initially as well, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use double-list comprehension.
`[ [] ]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).